# Switch case giving me an error

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

I have the following type of code:

```
String strGroup = Request.QueryString["group"];

switch(strGroup.ToString){
    case "Clients":
        // do something here
        break;
    case "Addresses":
        // do something here
    break;
    case "Matters":
        // do something here
    break;
    case "Individuals":
        // do something here
     break;
    case "Organisations":
        // do something here
    break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

But it's giving the following error:

A value of an integral type expected
for
switch(strGroup.ToString){

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since strGroup is already a string, can't you just do the following and avoid a redundant call to .ToString()?

```
switch(strGroup)
```

Comment: This is also safer because you won't get a null pointer exception if the string is null.  (And it will be null if the query string doesn't exist, which is a realistic case to handle.)

Comment: @Servy: It's outside the scope of this question but given that the input is coming directly from the querystring, it should definitely be tested for validity before use.

Comment: the 'default' should take care of everything that's not a valid test case, so if you don't .toString it and every valid case has a case statement, the default is where any code would go to handle any invalid values.

Answer (score 11):

Change it to this:

```
switch(strGroup.ToString())
```

`ToString()` is a method, not a property.  Therefore, you need to have the empty parenthesis.

Comment: Yes, oshirowanen, your problem is not use toString() as a function